# How to select a dictionary which is in a List<Task<Dictionary>>> to display on listbox

Tags: c#, .net, list, dictionary, task

I have to display a list of words from my dictionary into a list box.
I had to use tasks since I needed to use async for the assignment.

```cs
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    files.Add(filePath);
    files.Add(filePath2);
    List<Task<Dictionary<string, int>>> tasks = new List<Task<Dictionary<string, int>>>();
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        tasks.Add(wordreaderasync(file));
        
    }
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
    listBox1.DataSource = tasks[0];
    listBox1.DisplayMember = "Value";
    listBox1.DisplayMember = "Key";
    
}

public async Task<Dictionary<string, int>> wordreaderasync(string filename)
{
    var lines = await File.ReadAllLinesAsync(filename);

    var arrayfilter1 = lines.AsParallel().Where(x => x != string.Empty).Select(x => x.ToLower().Trim().Replace(",", "").Replace("'", ""));

    var arrayfilter2 = arrayfilter1.SelectMany(x => x.Split(" "));
    
    Dictionary<string, int> wordDictionary = new Dictionary<string, int>();
    
    arrayfilter2.ToList().ForEach(x =>
    {
        if (wordDictionary.ContainsKey(x))
        {
            wordDictionary[x] += 1;
        }
        else
        {
            wordDictionary.Add(x, 1);
        }
    });
    return wordDictionary;
}
```

I basically want to load the wordDictionary to my listbox. I do not understand how to exreact it from the list.

Comment: You Buttton.Click handler should be async: `private async void button3_Click()`. Then: `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);` (not clear why you run two tasks but you - try to - use just one). After that `listBox1.DataSource = null; listBox1.DisplayMember = "Key"; listBox1.ValueMember = "Value"; listBox1.DataSource = tasks[0].Result.ToList();` (you're setting `DisplayMember` twice). -- Assuming WinForms: add the require Tag that defines the UI platform.

Comment: `var arrayfilter2 = arrayfilter1.SelectMany(x => x.Split());`

Comment: `listBox1.DataSource = tasks.SelectMany(task => task.Result);` This will try to merge your several Dictionaries into an `IEnumareble<KeyValuePair<string, int>>`. Please bear in mind that you will lost the *unique key constraint* with this approach.

Comment: @rishabh111 Did any of the suggested / proposed solution work for you?